# How do you check/change iOS version in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I heard that a new version of iOS came out the other day, and wanted to know if my React Native project would be using that version by default when I build it with XCode, and if not, how can I force it to?

**My Questions Are:**

1) How do you check what version of iOS a React Native app is using?

2) How do you update the version of iOS in a React Native app?

**UPDATE:**

Based on @Simon's answer, I have one more question:

3) What determines the default version that a given project has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Xcode to change an iOS project's target target iOS version.  XCode > Project Navigator > "General" tab > Deployment Info > Target.  You will the "ios/Quevera.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" file will now have an entry like "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;".

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your reply. I updated the original question to include one more question, if you have any insight.

Answer (score 4):

Go to ios folder and then go to Podfile. At the top, find ios version and change it.