# React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found after using stripe react native

Tags: xcode, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

after using library https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native.   in my RN project.

I use workspace button to build my project.

For debug build on ios, works 100% fine.

**But For release build on ios,
`React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h` not found.**

any ideas?

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting? [Check this to see how to see what iOS version you are targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560392/how-do-you-check-change-ios-version-in-react-native)

It says that the Stripe React Native SDK targets iOS version 11 and above.

Comment: Or maybe [this can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919645/4083414)

Comment: This is a problem with the React Native build process not specific to the Stripe package. Another answer that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919645/